Getting 500 internal server error while try to connect to signalR server behind the YARP
I have created a signalR services and having YARP as reverse proxy. I am adding the signalR configuration dynamically using InMemoryConfigProvider.
When I try to connect with SIgnalR client build in Dotnet then I am getting 500 error code while connection to services
Sample Client Code
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("``http://localhost:5191/demohub``").Build();
connection.On<string>("newMessage", (message)) =>
{
Console.WriteLine(message);
});
await connection.StartAsync();
await connection.SendAsync("Subscribe");
Console.ReadLine();
await connection.StopAsync();
Adding Config and loading in memory
    var signalRconfig = new RouteConfig
    {
        RouteId = "demohub",
        Match = new RouteMatch()
        {
            Path = "/demohub"
        },
        Order = 3,
        ClusterId = "signalR"
    };
    var signalRCluster = new ClusterConfig
    {
        ClusterId = "signalR",
        Destinations = new Dictionary<string, DestinationConfig>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
            { 
                "signalRDestination", 
                new DestinationConfig()
                {
                    Address = "http://localhost:5100"
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    routeConfigManager.Routes.Add(signalRconfig);
    routeConfigManager.clusterConfigs.Add(signalRCluster);
    var config = new RouteConfigManager();  
    builder.Services.AddReverseProxy().LoadFromMemory(config.GetRouteConfig().Routes, config.GetRouteConfig().clusterConfigs);  

is anyone tried to have signalR behind YARP as documentation is not clear. I have added UseSessionAffinity added in pipeline.

Could you please share the 500 error 's details error message?
